# Remove junks('[',']',' etc) appended to values from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a collated json file and it is converted to a csv file

```
appended_data = []
for file in glob.glob('data-part.json'):
    dfjson = pd.read_json(file,encoding='utf-8',lines=True,dtype=str,error_bad_lines=False)
    appended_data.append(dfjson)
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
appended_data.to_csv("data.csv",index = False)
```

However on opening the convert csv file, it looks like this (snippet is shown below)

```
color   gear_type   oil_type    material    date_purchase
[]  ['Helical'] ['Synthetic']   ['Composite']   20201505
[]  ['Axle']    ['High Mileage']    ['Asphalt'] 20201505
nan ['Front-Axle']  ['Synthetic']   ['Vulcanised']  20201505
nan ['Bevel']   ['Conventional']    ['Carbon black']    20201505
```

But need the csv file to look like this instead (since some searches need to be done on it)

```
color   gear_type   oil_type    material    date_purchase
nan Helical Synthetic   Composite   20201505
nan Axle    High Mileage    Asphalt 20201505
nan Front-Axle  Synthetic   Vulcanised  20201505
nan Bevel   Conventional    Carbon black    20201505
```

How to catch these junks('[',']' etc) and normalize data

Comment: Have a look into the Dataframe.replace method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Tried `df.replace(regex={'^\[\'.*': '', '.*\'\]$': '','^\[\]$':''})` but no change in the dataframe..